# Why does Windows 10 still ask me to confirm deletions of files on my iPhone, when it doesn't for files on my hard drive?

Tags: iphone

I already turned off [file delete confirmation](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/3-ways-to-change-the-confirm-on-delete-dialog-in-windows-10/) for my Windows 10, and this Dialog no longer appears for the files on my C:\ drive.

But after I plug my iPhone into my Windows 10 thru USB, this Dialog still appears whenever I delete a file on my iPhone. Please see screenshot below.

Why does the Delete Confirmation Dialog still appear on my Windows 10, whenever I delete files on my iPhone?

I don't require immediate file deletion. I can happily keep the Recycle Bin as a safety net, so that when I click "Delete", files are moved to the Recycle Bin first and can be undeleted. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: You may have the same message with usb drives as windows does not have trash for usb devices like keys or phone. Try shift-delete(from numeric keypad)  on windows to suppress message.

Comment: @PtitXav - USB drives behave the same way. Shift/Del prompts an 'are you sure' message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because there's no safety net - the file will not go to trash, it will be immediately deleted, permanently.

The same happens if you try to 'hard' delete directly from Windows' own desktop using Shift/Del instead of just Del. The same is true of network file delete.

[image]

If you change that Properties setting From 'Custom size" to "Don't move files to the Recycle Bin…" then Shift/Del from the internal drives won't ask you. [I can't test whether this will also apply to the iPhone, but it ought to follow a similar rule-set.]

**WARNING:** Toggling this will remove the recycle bin functionality — that is, the recycle bin will no longer operate. If you want to remove any 'are you sure' messages for a permanent delete, you have to beware the consequences.

Comment: doesn't this mean the recycle bin will not work anymore? What if the user would like to continue using the recycle bin?

Comment: Correct. Toggling this will remove the recycle bin functionality. If you want to remove any 'are you sure' messages for a permanent delete, you have to beware the consequences.

Comment: thanks. can you please see the para. that I added to my edited post, just above the screenshot?

Comment: Windows can't do that. It can't do it for networked drives or USB sticks either. The iPhone mounts to Windows like a USB stick.